# HiddenField does not send value to client-side javascript code during button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Button which calls other buttons:

```csharp
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button3_Click(this, null);
  Button4_Click(this, null);
}
```

Button3 sets double values in HiddenField:

```csharp
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    if (Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text) > 3)
    {
      double count1 +=1;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text) > 0)
    {
      double count2 += 1;
    }

    HiddenField_count1.Value = count.ToString(); 
    HiddenField_count2.Value = count2.ToString(); 
  }
}
```

Then take values in javascript:

```
<div id="divRatio" >
  <h3 id="ratio_N">0</h3>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

```js
function calc()
{
  var count_1 = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField_count1.ClientID%>').value;
  var count_2 = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField_count2.ClientID%>').value;
  var count_ratio = count_2 / count_1;
  document.getElementById("ratio_N").innerHTML = String('ratio:' + count_ratio );
}
```

Then call `calc()` in Button2:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional"  runat="server" >
  <Triggers> 
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2"  />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="buttonR"  OnClick="Button2_Click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False" Text="calc"  OnClientClick ="calc();"  />
```

The problem is that `HiddenField` only gets values after clicking Button2 second time.  I made a research on the internet but didn`t found a good solution

Comment: I was updating my edits but you were faster but I take the heed thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it makes perfect sense.

You have this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" 
  CssClass="buttonR"  
   OnClick="Button2_Click" 
   Font-Bold="True" 
   Font-Overline="False" 
   Text="calc"  
   OnClientClick ="calc();"  />
```

So when you click above, your client side javascript call "calc()" runs FIRST. At that point, the server side code event has not run. So, your calc() runs, but without the server side code having run, the values are not set.

NOW the server side code runs, sets the value(s) on that page.

Now, next time you click the button again, then calc() (client side) has the correct values and works, and then of course the server side code runs.

So, yes, you have to click the button 2 times for your client side code to work, since the server side code has not yet run.

So, the "key concept" to what you see is that the client side code attached to that button runs FIRST, and THEN the server side code runs.

Since the client side code is based on values set by the server side code, then you have to click 2 times, since the first time you click, your client side code runs BEFORE the server side code.

but, since your client side code is OH SO VERY simple? Why not move that code logic to the server side code anyway?

so, REMOVE you needless client side code and do it this way:

markup:

```
<div id="divRatio" >
  <h3 id="ratio_N" runat="server"  >0</h3>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

by adding the runat=server to above, then code behind can modify that value.

And thus we now have this:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button3_Click(this, null);
    Button4_Click(this, null);
    
    ratio_N.InnerText =  (count_2.Value / count_1.Value).ToString();

}
```

So, really I see VERY little reason to try and run that simple client side code. but, regardless of above, the simple answer is the client side code you have will run BEFORE the server side button click runs, and hence on first button click, the client side code does not yet have the server value(s) that are setup and changed AFTER that the client side code stub runs. Since it needs the value(s) from the server side code (which has NOT yet run), then that code actually needs to run AFTER the server side code, not before.

Comment: Is there other solution cause later want to put some count down which is better done in javascript and and want to send server data to client side to determine the length of count down?

Comment: Even with a update panel, that STILL means a standard post-back, page load triggers, code behind runs, and ONLY after that page (or page part with update panel) travels back to the client side will you see the results. However, a count down or progress bar is a  MASSIVE and a Mount Everest of a different type of question and goal here.  The server does not "send" data to the browser, the browser HAS to request the information.  So, you could create a web method, or if you REALLY need a type of web socket pipeline from the server, then you need to adopt SignalR. I would consider ajax calls.